# Hide function definitions from the history for easier debug

Tags: r, debugging, ide, rstudio

Just suppose we are debugging a function `foo()`, and we want to modify it again and again and run it with some arguments - `foo(bar="Hello", baz="How are you?")` - to be sure the problem is solved.

After a modification of the `foo()` body, we run the lines of the function definition - to make the function modified - and now, we have to search over the history for the line containing `foo(bar="Hello", baz="How are you?")` to see if the modified `foo()` works properly. 
Searching the history can also be replaced by continued pressing the "Up" key until it reaches before the function definition, when the last time we run `foo(bar="Hello", baz="How are you?")`.

The other possibility is to keep `foo(bar="Hello", baz="How are you?")` in the clipboard and every time we modify the `foo()` body, we just paste `foo(bar="Hello", baz="How are you?")` from the clipboard and run it.

But all of these solutions are quite hard if we are modifying several functions with long bodies at the same time. The best possibility I have taught is to hide the function definitions from the history - when we are working with native R environment or with IDEs like RStudio. Is there any possibility to do this? Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `source()` the function definition from file rather than "copy-paste" (or otherwise run) the function code block from the IDE/editor. Sourcing won't show in the R console if you do this (by default anyway). Most reasonable editors have a keyboard shortcut to source/load the function buffer/file/window into R via `source()` rather that by "pasting" - on Emacs+ESS it is <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> for example.

You could use a sensible editor like Emacs with ESS which doesn't interleave code sent from code buffers into the R buffer, so you don't have to up-key back from the function definition, only back through the history.

At least on Linux you can use the common <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then start typing the first few characters of the function call you want, which will do a reverse search for the thing you are typing and then upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> will run that command/line.

Comment: In RStudio, you can use `Ctrl + up` to do a reverse search.